# C++: Loop and Function

Tags: c++

Iwant to use a Function, in order to calculate average of some numbers. I dont understand, Why the  Code is false and I can not simply use `for(float j: Noten)` in the Funktion "Mittel"?

```
 float Mittel (float Noten[5]) {
    
    float sum = 0 ; 
    
    for (float i : Noten){
        sum+=i ;
    }
    return sum/5 ; 
}


int main() {
    float Noten[5];
    
    for (int i=0; i<5 ; i++){
        cout << "give Note "<< i+1<< endl; ; 
        cin>>Noten[i];
    }
    
    cout << Mittel(Noten);
    
    return 0; 
}
```

using `for (int i=0; i<5 ; i++)` instead. it works, but why?

Comment: The syntax `float Noten[5]` is misleading: *normally* this would declare an array. But, misleadingly, in a function parameter declaration, this syntax is instead just an alias for `float* Noten`: `Noten` is a raw pointer! That’s why your `for` loop does not work.

Comment: If you use `std::array` instead of C-style arrays, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`float Mittel (float Noten[5])` is actually `float Mittel (float Noten[])`/`float Mittel (float* Noten)`; so size information is lost :-/

You might pass reference to array to keep size information:

```
float Mittel (const float (&Noten)[5])
```

A more generic would be to take a `std::span`:

```
float Mittel (std::span<const float> Noten)
{
    float sum = 0 ; 
    
    for (float i : Noten){
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum / Noten.size();
    // or even
    // return std::accumulate(Noten.begin(), Noten.end(), 0.f) / Noten.size();
}
```